# Mechanism of multiple call for one script in the same time

Tags: linux, filesystems, process

I have the ruby script which is calling from different places in the same time(with defferent options).
Is it safely and how this mechanism realized in linux? I mean what happens with file after calling it from a few programs in the same time? Is calls parallelized and work with different copy of file?

Comment: It depends from the script. If it works with relative (to the calling point) path you can find e.g. different copies of the output files; if it works reading and writing the same files with absolute path, you can have an inpredictible behaviour... each instance starts and goes forward usually without knowing the existence of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has its own address space, i.e. each process can only access its own virtual memory and not the memory of other processes.  Executables and shared libraries are mapped into the process's address space.

In your example of a ruby script, the script is only read and interpreted by the ruby interpreter which builds a compiled version of the script in its own memory and then executes the program from that compiled version.